# To do list jquery, cross out item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I"m making a very simple to-do list with jquery. I have an input box for adding thing and once entered it will print out that underneath:

HTML:

```
    <html>
          <head>
             <title>My to-do list</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/list.css" >
         </head>

        <body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/list.js"></script>
  <div id="empty-top"></div>
  <div align= "center" class="wrapper">
    <h2>Add thing to your to-do list</h2>
    <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="To-do-list" >
  </div>

  <div class = "things">

  </div>

        </body>
   </html>
```

my js file:

```
$(function(){

  $("#input").keypress(function(e){

if(e.which == 13){

  var content = $("#input").val();

  $("<li>" + content + "<input id= 'check' type='checkbox'> </li>").appendTo(".things");

  };

});
```

//I want to check if the box is checked. If it is then I want to insert the  tag to cross that item. This function, however does not work. I also tried ("input").is(":checked") or ("input").prop("checked",true) but still doesn't do what I wanted.

```
$("#check").click(function(){

  var box = $(this);

  $("<del>").insertBefore("<li>");

  $("</del>").insertAfter("</li>");

});
```

});

Thank you!!!!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried .wrap() - it looks like all you want to do is wrap an element in the del tag http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can't append LI elements to a DIV, it should be an UL or OL parent element, and you can't wrap the LI in a DEL, as a DEL element can't be a child of an UL, so you have to wrap the inner element, and unwrap it when the checkbox is unchecked again.

As for the event handler, you can attach that when you create the element, and you should be listening to the change event etc.

```
$(function () {
    $("#input").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var content = $("#input").val();
            var li  = $('<li />', {
                    text : this.value
                }),
                inp = $('<input />', {
                    'class': 'check',
                    type   : 'checkbox',
                    on : {
                        change: function() {
                            if (this.checked) {
                                $(this).closest('li').wrapInner('<del />');
                            }else{
                                $(this).unwrap();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            $('.things').append( li.append(inp) );
        };
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rpnv8/1/)

Comment: Can you explain the on {change function()} part a little bit? It works. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: It's just an event handler, like `$('input').on('change', function...` and it checks if the checkbox is checked, if it is, then it wraps the inner elements in `<del>`, and if it isn't it unwraps the elements again.

Comment: Why does it need to unwrap. If else, it just doesn't add the del tag. Just wondering

Comment: If you check the box, it wraps the elements, and if you uncheck the box again, it has to remove the wrapping elements, otherwise they would still be wrapped ?

Answer (score 0):

To see if your checkbox is checked, you can use:

```
$("input").get(0).checked
```

I would suggest adding a class in your CSS:

```
.complete{text-decoration:line-through}
```

And then add the `complete` class if `checked`

```
if($("input").get(0).checked){
   $('corresponding-list-item').addClass('complete');
}
```